# How do I update my Modem Firmware

Tags: modem, firmware

I have a Linksys Cable Modem BEFCMU10 version 2. Is there a way I can update the firmware. I've read that only the ISP can update the firmware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like my modem can only be upgraded from the ISP.

Answer (score 0):

Check the administration page of the modem. If there is an update button or a button that allows you to select update files, you can do it yourself (provided the download is available from Linksys).

Answer (score 0):

this forum might help

http://forums.linksysbycisco.com/linksys/board/message?comm_cc=ANZ&comm_lang=en&board.id=Cable&message.id=452#M452